# Imported from live to localhost phypadmin links not working

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have imported my live website to localhost xampp after setup i am unable to open link associated to it for example :- my website address locally is localhost/abc i am unable to open localhost/abc/contact-us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all domain occurrences to your local domain
If you're using wp-cli

you can do it with

```
wp search-replace "your-domain-name.com" "localhost/abc"
```

if not you can open your sql dump in text editor and do find-replace there

Also there are a lot of different plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Also check that your permalinks are configured correctly and you have proper .htaccess file